# Showing array elements in Lotusscript

Tags: arrays, dynamic, lotusscript, lotus

I have created an array where elements will be added if a condition is filled. I want to show the values of the array in a column of a table.

```
If CStr(reqPanelRes(0)) = "Accepted" Then
    totalAccepted = totalAccepted + 1
    AccPanels(i) = reqNumDoc.Panel_Intranet_ID(0)
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Here AccPanels(i) is the dynamic array. I am not able to show the values of this array in a column separated by comma in Lotusscript.

Comment: How do you store the values in the document? Have you tried NotesItem.appendToTextList ?

Comment: I am declaring an array like this:  Redim AccPanels(10) as String. Then I wrote the code mentioned above.

Comment: Nice. But AccPanels is declared only in memory at runtime. if you don't explicitly write it back to the document and save the document, the values are lost when the code ends.  Don't you have something like doc.replaceitemvalue("accPanels",accPanels) in your code ?

Comment: I do not want to save the values. I just want to send the values of the array in a mail. Is there a way to show the elements of the array?

Comment: And how do you create the mail and the table? Basically, to create the mail, you write strings to a rich text item on a document, and one of the strings could be:  Join(AccPanels, ", ")

Comment: Show us the code you are using to create the email so we can help you modify it to show the values you want.

Comment: Normally columns are part of views. My crystal ball didn't tell me that you want a to display them in richtext.  The join() function may be your friend...